# VB.Net webforms App: Hangfire background jobs library "Unable to cast object" error at startup

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, hangfire, global-asax

I'm working on a Asp.Net project where I'm trying to add "Hangfire" library for background jobs. I've installed all required packages according [doccumentation](https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/getting-started/aspnet-applications.html) and also created the test database.

I've also added the required startup methods in Global.asax.vb (had to convert from C#, given in the example, to VB.net) so my file looks like this:

```
Imports Hangfire
Imports Hangfire.SqlServer

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits HttpApplication

    Sub Application_Start(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        ' Fires when the application is started
        Try
            HangfireAspNet.Use(GetHangfireServers)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.Assert(False, "Not Yet Ready")
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Iterator Function GetHangfireServers() As IEnumerable(Of IDisposable)
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170).UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer().UseRecommendedSerializerSettings().UseSqlServerStorage("Data Source=xxx,00000;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx", New SqlServerStorageOptions With {
            .CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            .SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            .QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
            .UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = True,
            .DisableGlobalLocks = True
        })
        Yield New BackgroundJobServer()
    End Function

End Class
```

And the

```
HangfireAspNet.Use(GetHangfireServers)
```

line is throwing the next exception:

> Unable to cast object of type 'VB$StateMachine_6_GetHangfireServers' to type 'System.Func`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.IDisposable]]

I've verified that the connection string is OK and it connects to the test database with no problems, but I'm stuck regarding the exception.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved my problem, just putting the function inside the Use():

```
Public Shared Sub Init()
    Dim connStr = "Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx"
    HangfireAspNet.Use(
        Iterator Function()
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.SetDataCompatibilityLevel(CompatibilityLevel.Version_170).UseSimpleAssemblyNameTypeSerializer().UseRecommendedSerializerSettings().UseSqlServerStorage(connStr, New SqlServerStorageOptions With {
                .CommandBatchMaxTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                .SlidingInvisibilityTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
                .QueuePollInterval = TimeSpan.Zero,
                .UseRecommendedIsolationLevel = True,
                .DisableGlobalLocks = True
            })
            Yield New BackgroundJobServer()
        End Function
    )
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB you have to use AddressOf in your proc call, i.e.:

```
HangfireAspNet.Use(AddressOf GetHangfireServers)
```